# How can I set right click->Options->Keep in Dock on a program that only runs for 10 seconds?

Tags: macos, dock, app-bundle

I have a program (.app bundle) that I wrote for OS X Mountain Lion.  It performs a task that only I need and it only runs for 10 seconds.  Once a day, I click on it (Launchpad->click my app) and 10 seconds later, it is done and it closes.  I want it to be in the Dock all day everyday so that I can just click on it when I need it and so my wife can find it when she needs to run it.  The problem is that it does not run long enough for me to right click on it, pick Options and then click Keep in Dock.  Is there anyway I can add it to the Dock? or am I going to have to modify my app so that the first time it runs it waits a minute to give me a chance to add it to the dock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two possible solutions:

1. Locate your application in the Finder, and drag its icon into the Dock.
2. Immediately after launching the application, as soon as its icon appears in the Dock, quickly drag it to a different location/position in the Dock. The action of moving it from its default position at the end of the Dock will have the same effect as **Options > Keep in Dock**.